# Axler LADR, Excercise 3.14, ed. 2.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume

- $W$ is a finite dimensional vector space.
- $V$ is a vector space.
- $T \in L(V,W)$, "$T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $W$"

Show the following equivalence:
$$T\ \text{injective} \iff \exists S\in L(W,V)|ST=I_V $$

Here $S$ is a linear map from $W$ to $V$ and $I_V$ is the identity map on $V$.

$(\impliedby)$ is somewhat trivial, since injectivity is required for $ST$ to make sense.

I have trouble seeing that $(\implies)$ neccesarily holds if $T$ is not onto, since that would mean that there are elements in $W$ that are not "hit" by $T$, but at the same time if $S$ is to be defined, it must map every element in $W$ to $V$, even those elements that were not "hit" by $T$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "injectivity is required for $ST$ to make sense". Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $T\in L(V,W)$ is injective. Note that $\dim(V)\leq \dim(W)$. Let $\left\{w_1, \dots ,w_k\right\}$ be a basis of $\text{im}(T)$ and complete to a basis $\{w_1,\dots ,w_k,w_{k+1}, \dots ,w_m\}$ of $W$, furthermore, let $v_i$ be defined such that $L(v_i)=w_i$ for $i\leq k$ (note that the $v_i$'s or linearly independent).

I claim that $\{v_i\mid i\leq k\}$ is a basis of $V$, indeed, $k=\dim(\text{im}(T))=\dim(V)$ as $T$ is injective. Now define $S\in L(W,V)$ by $S(w_i)=v_i$ and $S(w_{i+j})=0$. Then $S\circ T=I_V$ as you can verify. The elements that you don't hit, don't matter.